# Обновление видимых ячеек в tableView

Tags: swift, tableview

Подскажите как можно решить следующую проблему. Имеется tableView, который отображает список пользователей (имя + фото). Данные для таблицы хранятся в массиве (там кастомный класс - в нем имя и картинка в Data).

Проблема, что при первом отображении таблицы никакие фото для видимых на экране ячеек не загружаются, при прокрутке ниже для следующих ячеек все фотки есть, и так же если вернуться к началу таблицы, то для первых ячеек фотки отобразятся, хотя изначально их не было.

Вот часть моего кода:

```swift
// Здесь хранятся юзеры
var users = [UsersData]()

// Так формирую ячейки таблицы

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ListTableViewCell

cell.userName.text = users[indexPath.row].name!

if users[indexPath.row].photo != nil {
    cell.photoView.image = UIImage(data: users[indexPath.row].photo!)
} 

return cell

}
```

Пытался обновлять видимые ячейки таким образом - не дало никакого эффекта: ячейки красиво обновляются, но фоток нет. Если сделать свайп вниз и вернуться - загрузятся...

```swift
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .fade)
```

Comment: `tableView.reloadData()` пробовали?

Comment: да, тоже никакого эффекта

Comment: Если Вы делаете такую проверку users[indexPath.row].photo != nil, значит, фото почему-то там может не быть, возможно вы их подгружаете и заполняете массив. Если это так, то обновлять ячейки нужно после загрузки фото.

Comment: Откуда берутся фото в массиве?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема действительно оказалась в несовременной загрузке данных. Фотографии попадали в массив медленнее, чем приходила команда на обновление таблицы.

Реализовал очередь с барьером - сперва убеждаюсь что все фотографии действительно загрузились (в это время показываю пустую таблицу), а затем выполняю tableView.reloadData()

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте загружать фото в отдельном потоке  асинхронно в ячейках. Возможно оно просто не успевает подгрузить сразу все.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    if users[indexPath.row].photo != nil {
        cell.photoView.image = UIImage(data: users[indexPath.row].photo!)
    } 
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло :(